# React-native: Unable to access JSON via fetch method

Tags: json, react-native, http-headers, fetch

- Fetch json from an url via POST method.

  ```
  var params= {
    method: "POST",
  headers: {      
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
  body: JSON.stringify({firstparam:"value",})
  };

  fetch("http://url",params)
  ```
- I have specified `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but in the reply I'm getting this following message in the firefox browser:
  **Cross-Origin Request Blocked:** `The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://url. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`
- None of parameters specified in headers are applied.Content type is always set to `text/html` instead of `application/json` as specified in request headers.

What am i missing?What changes shall i make to apply the Headers parameters and set Content-Type to `application/json`

Comment: ... the CORS headers need to be on the *server*. It would be kind of pointless if clients determined what the server allowed.

Comment: i am making a request from client side so wouldn't it be necessary to specify it for getting response from server?

Comment: The server sets those headers to indicate it accepts cross-origin requests. The client doesn't determine what the server allows. It doesn't make any sense for the *client* to indicate it accepts cross-origin requests. Fortunately all of this is trivially searchable.